# Open generated Web Page with WebBrowser object in VB

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'd like to know if it possible to show HTML page created in VB using WebBrowser object without using files on disk.
That is, create HTML file in memory and show it within WebBrowser object.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution. It's not so complicated. 
The solution is to run from the VB: 
*

- WebBrowserObject.Navigate "about:HTML TEXT"
- It works, I've checked it.

Comment: There is a length limit on urls.

Answer (score 4):

Using Visual Basic in .Net Framework...

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><a href='http://www.mywebsite.com'>My Web Site</a></body></html>"
```

In old Visual Basic 6, try...

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Open
WebBrowser1.Document.Write "<html><body><a href='http://www.mywebsite.com'>My Web Site</a></body></html>"
WebBrowser1.Document.Close
```

Answer (score 2):

First wait for the DocumentComplete event (navigate to about:blank if you start from scratch), then use the [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.domdocument.aspx)'s IPersistMoniker (recommended if you want to provide a base url) or IPersistStreamInit interface to load [HTML content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can find an example (the LoadHtmlIntoBrowser method) in the csexwb project.

Comment: Your load HTML content link is death.